# US visa valid for travelling from the UK instead of India?

Tags: usa, uk, india

I have a 10 year B1/B2 US visa from India. I am moving to the UK. Would be visa be valid for visiting the US from the UK?

Comment: Why would you think otherwise ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. A visa grants you entry into the country, regardless of where you are.